# External JS file not finding controls, but work with quickwatch

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following code in my aspx file:

```
var blah = "<%= lblErrorsMain.ClientID %>"
```

and here is the external js file:

```
function ShowShowScans2() {
    oWebDialogWindow2 =  document.getElementById(blah);
    oWebDialogWindow2.set_windowState($IG.DialogWindowState.Normal);
    return false;
}
```

When the code runs, it always bombs out at the oWebDialogWindow2.set_windowState($IG.DialogWindowState.Normal) that Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'set_windowState': object is null or undefined.
When I break into the code and hover over oWebDialogWindow2, it's null. But, when I open a quickwatch window and do document.getElementById(blah), I get access to the object.  What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 'document.getElementById', in the declaration and assignment of the variable.

If you are in 'FormView':

```
var blah = document.getElementById('<%= FormView1.FindControl("lblErrorsMain").ClientID %>');
```

The other way is as follows:

```
var blah = document.getElementById('<%= lblErrorsMain.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: I have been following the directions of other posts how to effectively use an external js file and that's why I did it that way.  Right now, it is working and I have no idea why.